# Сочетания клавиш для комментирования строк(и) в Python коде в Sublime Text

Tags: python

Какие сочетания клавиш комментирует строку в Sublime Text?
Речь идет о Python коде.

Comment: Вы хоть попробовали задать тот же самый вопрос (первое предложение) Google?

Comment: [Почитайте](http://goo.gl/ev2DZb)

Comment: Комбинация Shift-F3

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: мне нужна комбинация клавиатуры для коментировки а не #

Comment: Например Shift-F3    но не это

Comment: @Artem, вы можете уточнить о какой среде идет речь? В какой программе вы ищете  комбинацию клавиатуры ?

Comment: @MaxU я пишу програму и мне закоментировали огромное количество строк и я ищю как в питоне с помощью комбинации клавишь раскомментировать строки

Comment: Что значит "в питоне"? О какой программе идет речь - iPython, Jupyter Notebook, Notepad++, vi, etc.? Или вы думаете что у всех в мире программ одинаковые комбинации (shortcuts)? ;-)

Comment: Я пишу Физз Базз без цикла

Comment: щяс скину скрин

Comment: ааааа в Sublime Text

Answer (score 2):

```
ctrl+/
```

выделяешь строки, нажимаешь, в этих строках добавляется в начало строки диез.

Comment: и правда, гугл очень помогает, я слышал.

Comment: нет не работает

Comment: а нет спасибо работает